# Scalar Curvature on a given surface

Tags: tensors

I have a very basic understanding of how to compute the ricci curvature tensor...I know a considerable amount about it, but don't know how to compute it. Could someone give me an example of how to find the scalar curvature of a given surface... Say that it went, in spherical coordinates, from x, $\pi/2$, $\pi/4$, time 0 to $2x$, 0, $\pi/4$, time $t$. What is the scalar curvature of this 4D manifold?

P.s. I'm still learning how to type on this so I don't know how to type Pi into this... Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

[This is a good link](http://physicspages.com/2014/10/21/ricci-tensor-and-curvature-scalar-for-a-sphere/) where the computation of the Ricci scalar is explained.

Comment: Thank you, that helped... I actually found that the other day... And it helped... Kind of funny... 